# Integrating Apollo client global config with React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

When we configure the Apollo client, with Apollo links, we do so globally outside of the React component tree.

For example, with `apollo-link-error` we define what should happen when there's a network error, or when there's an authentication error. In both these cases I want to update React state in response. For example to show an error popup, or perhaps in the case of an authentication error to log the user out and change a piece of React state that represents their logged in status.

Because the initial global client setup happens outside of React, React doesn't know about it, and it feels awkward to affect to component tree from outside.

Am I thinking about this the right way?